# Fill missing sequence values with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame with missing values for "SNAP_ID". I'd like to fill in the missing values with floating point values based on a sequence from the previous non-missing value (lag()?). I would really like to achieve this using just dplyr if possible.

Assumptions:

1. There will never be missing data as the first or last row I'm generating the missing dates based on missing days between a min and max of a data set
2. There can be multiple gaps in the data set

Current data:

```
                  end SNAP_ID
1 2015-06-26 12:59:00     365
2 2015-06-26 13:59:00     366
3 2015-06-27 00:01:00      NA
4 2015-06-27 23:00:00      NA
5 2015-06-28 00:01:00      NA
6 2015-06-28 23:00:00      NA
7 2015-06-29 09:00:00     367
8 2015-06-29 09:59:00     368
```

What I want to achieve:

```
                  end SNAP_ID
1 2015-06-26 12:59:00     365.0
2 2015-06-26 13:59:00     366.0
3 2015-06-27 00:01:00     366.1
4 2015-06-27 23:00:00     366.2
5 2015-06-28 00:01:00     366.3
6 2015-06-28 23:00:00     366.4
7 2015-06-29 09:00:00     367.0
8 2015-06-29 09:59:00     368.0
```

As a data frame:

```
df <- structure(list(end = structure(c(1435323540, 1435327140, 1435363260, 
    1435446000, 1435449660, 1435532400, 1435568400, 1435571940), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt")), SNAP_ID = c(365, 366, NA, NA, NA, NA, 367, 368)), .Names = c("end", 
    "SNAP_ID"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

This was my attempt at achieving this goal, but it only works for the first missing value:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(end) %>%
  mutate(SNAP_ID=ifelse(is.na(SNAP_ID),lag(SNAP_ID)+0.1,SNAP_ID))

                  end SNAP_ID
1 2015-06-26 12:59:00   365.0
2 2015-06-26 13:59:00   366.0
3 2015-06-27 00:01:00   366.1
4 2015-06-27 23:00:00      NA
5 2015-06-28 00:01:00      NA
6 2015-06-28 23:00:00      NA
7 2015-06-29 09:00:00   367.0
8 2015-06-29 09:59:00   368.0
```

The outstanding answer from @mathematical.coffee below:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(end) %>%
  group_by(tmp=cumsum(!is.na(SNAP_ID))) %>%
  mutate(SNAP_ID=SNAP_ID[1] + 0.1*(0:(length(SNAP_ID)-1))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-tmp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: new version works for any number of NA runs.
This one doesn't need `zoo`, either.

First, notice that `tmp=cumsum(!is.na(SNAP_ID))` groups the `SNAP_ID`s such groups of the same `tmp` consist of one non-NA value followed by a run of NA values.

Then group by this variable and just add .1 to the first SNAP_ID to fill out the NAs:

```
df %>% 
  arrange(end) %>%
  group_by(tmp=cumsum(!is.na(SNAP_ID))) %>%
  mutate(SNAP_ID=SNAP_ID[1] + 0.1*(0:(length(SNAP_ID)-1)))

                  end SNAP_ID tmp
1 2015-06-26 12:59:00   365.0   1
2 2015-06-26 13:59:00   366.0   2
3 2015-06-27 00:01:00   366.1   2
4 2015-06-27 23:00:00   366.2   2
5 2015-06-28 00:01:00   366.3   2
6 2015-06-28 23:00:00   366.4   2
7 2015-06-29 09:00:00   367.0   3
8 2015-06-29 09:59:00   368.0   4
```

Then you can drop the `tmp` column afterwards (add `%>% select(-tmp)` to the end).

---

EDIT: this is the **old version** which doesn't work for subsequent runs of `NA`s.

If your aim is to fill each NA with the previous value + 0.1, you can use `zoo`'s `na.locf` (which fills each `NA` with the previous value), along with `cumsum(is.na(SNAP_ID))*0.1` to add the extra 0.1.

```
library(zoo)
df %>% 
  arrange(end) %>%
  mutate(SNAP_ID=ifelse(is.na(SNAP_ID),
                       na.locf(SNAP_ID) + cumsum(is.na(SNAP_ID))*0.1,
                       SNAP_ID))
```

Comment: Thanks for the outstanding answer! The only minor correction is that you need to ungroup() before the select(-tmp). ungroup() drives me insane sometimes.